# CSOM SharePoint - Add Item to List with proper FieldValues - FieldLookUpValues

Tags: c#, sharepoint, lookup, csom, listitem

I hope somebody can help me with my issue.
My actual workflow to get add a new item to my list in SharePoint looks like this:

```
                using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(Website))
                {                       
                    List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List");
                    ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                    //add Item 
                    ListItem listItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                    listItem["Effort"] = 5.0;
                    listItem["ItemStart"] = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
                    listItem["Workpackage"] = "PRG";
                    listItem.Update();

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
```

Pretty straight forward and it "works" except for the Item: listItem["Workpackage"] = "PRG";

If I fetch the list to show me all values in item.FieldValues I get that this is a FieldLookUpValue. I display it like so ((FieldLookupValue)value.Value).LookupValue.

My problem is, that I need to set this value to the item I add to the list because without it SharePoint doesn't recognize it in the right field.

If I use the code above I get that this field ["Workpackage"] is maybe write-protected or that I transferd the wrong data for this field. Thats why I think that I have to transfer the data as a LookUpValue, but I really don't get how to make this work.

I hope I could describe my problem as close as possible.
If you need any further information, please let me know.
And thanks for the help anyway!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73252/sharepoint-client-model-and-setting-up-lookup-field

You need to pass the ID of the item from the lookup list.

Comment: Hey anfalt, thanks for the link! I figuerd it out yesterday and the link gave me a similar solution like mine. I talked to the developer of the system which we use and I could resolve my problem.